# What sheep do you need to mate in order to try and get the rare pink sheep?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What types of sheep must you mate in order to have a chance in getting the pink sheep? What is the percent of getting it? I looked in the breeding section of the wiki and it said that you could technically get the pink sheep without the use of dyes.

Comment: On the wiki it says that you can get a rare pink sheep without dying the parents. I want to know what the percentage of that happening is.

Comment: Your question and your comments are at odds with each other.  You ask what you need to breed to get a pink sheep, but you're leaving comments that you want to know how to find one without breeding.  You may want to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: If you have a new question you are welcome to ask it as a new question. You're not allowed to use editing to fundamentally change your question. I've reverted the edit.

Comment: Uhhh. http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=72 (Questionable NSFW)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sheep colour traits are passed on by their parents, meaning you will probably need to find a pink sheep in order to breed a pink sheep, which is counter-intuitive. A chance of spawning a pink sheep using the Sheep Egg is 0.164%

Luckily, there's an easier way. You can [dye sheep different colours](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dyeing), and those colours are passed on to their children when they breed. Sheep dyed a certain colour will even keep that colour after being shorn, and having their wool regenerate!

To dye a Sheep Pink, you first need the items

- [Rose Red](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rose_Red) (from Roses)
- [Bonemeal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Meal) (from Bones)

Two items fairly easy to come by. Combining them in your inventory windows produces 2 [Pink Dye](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pink_Dye).

Use these Pink Dye items on a pair of sheep, and breed them normally. You'll have a small flock of pink sheep in no time!

Comment: I'm playing in a peaceful game. The wiki says I can get a pink sheep without doing that.

Comment: @YoungGuilo - You *can* find Pink sheep in the wild, but the odds are very unlikely, and cannot be counted on as a reliable way of getting Pink wool. As for Peaceful or not, I don't see that making a difference

Comment: I assume @YoungGuilo mentioned Peaceful mode because Bones will be harder to come by without Skeletons. However, they can still be found in chests in Jungle/Desert Temples.

Comment: @YoungGuilo - whoops, massive Derp on my part :-/ - been a while since I played on peaceful, completely forgot that skeletons would be in short supply

Comment: @YoungGuilo - Out of curiosity, what's stopping you from switching to 'Easy' for a (minecraft) night and collecting some bones?

Comment: Notch teaching kids how genetics work - if you dye yourself blue then your children will be blue too.

Comment: @nightcracker [Da Ba dee da ba dye](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BinWA0EenDY) ;)

Comment: @nightcracker Notch is just teaching kids about [Lamarckism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamarckism)! :)

Comment: I'm asking to find the rare pink sheep in game. It says on the wiki that you can get 1 without mating.

Answer (score 3):

White and red, of course.

The chance is pretty high. I once accidentally let one white sheep in with a herd of red ones (with an automatic feeder) and before long it was riddled with pink sheep.

Alternatively, just use pink dye on any sheep.

The reason the wiki says you can get pink sheep without dyes is because they spawn naturally in the world, though very rarely. It doesn't mean there's some secret breeding trick to get one.

Comment: Like accidentally washing a red hat with a load of whites :P

Comment: I thought only naturally coloured sheep (black,grey,white,brown etc) could "intermix" colours. Well, that's my learning covered for today!

Comment: @Robotnik That would make sense, wouldn't it. :) Which is why Minecraft can't possibly work that way!

Comment: I'm asking to find the rare pink sheep in game. It says on the wiki that you can get 1 without mating.

Comment: @YoungGuilo That's not what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers provided by SevenSidedDie and Robotnik are mostly correct, I'm going to address the details here.

A newborn sheep will be colored depending on the colors of the parents. The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep#Breeding) explains it quite well:

> If the parents have 'compatible' wool colors (meaning that the corresponding dye items could be combined into a third dye color), the resulting lamb will be a mix of their colors (e.g., blue sheep + white sheep = light blue lamb). Otherwise, the lamb will be the same color as one of the parents, chosen at random.

Thus, there are two ways to get a pink sheep: You can mate a red sheep (dye one with a [Rose Red](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rose_Red) dye) and a white sheep (either found naturally, or by dying one white with [Bone Meal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Meal), as suggested by Robotnik), or you can pre-mix the [Rose Red](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rose_Red) and [Bone Meal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Meal) together on a crafting table to make [Pink Dye](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pink_Dye), and then dye a sheep with that.

Thus, if you know what you're doing, the chance of obtaining a pink sheep is 100%. :-)